# Why razor executes a C# method inside a button click method on compilation without clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, session, razor

-ASP.NET 4.7 Web Application-

I hold some notifications in the session to show the user. I want to remove the session variable on button click.

**The idea is to make sure the user gets notified so as long as the user don't hit "Got it" button, I won't be removing the notifications from the session so that every time the users reload the page they will see the same notification window.**

I have a button in a modal as follows:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="clearSession()" data-dismiss="modal">Got it</button>
```

And this is the method supposed to be called on button click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearSession() {
        @{Session.Remove("WhatsNewList");}
    };
</script>
```

The problem is that  the following part of the code precompiles and executes even though the button is not clicked.

```
@{Session.Remove("Notifications");}
```

I want to know what is the reason for this and is there a way to prevent this.

I know I can call a C# method using Ajax or jQuery but I want to know if there is a way I can do it this way as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sourounding an expression Using @{ } will cause the expression to be evaluated server side before the page is loaded into the browser meaning the code will execute as soon as the page is requested.  So, the short answer is, you cannot do what you are trying to do using this approach.

Comment: Also to add this, the javascript function will be executed in the client's machine (in the browser) so there is no way to have that type of side effect to the backend directly from a client without sending a request of some sort.